# Integral Problem help

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given definite integral

$
f(t)=\int_{0}^{t} \frac{x^2+13x+36}{1+{\cos{x}}^{2}} dx
$

At what value of $t$ does the local max of $f(t)$ occur?

What I did is replace $x$ variable with $t$...

and the $f'(t)=\frac{x^2+13x+36}{1+{\cos{x}}^{2}}=0$
because looking for local extrema points is when the derivative is $0$.

So based on my knowledge, $t = -4$ and $-9$ when $f'(x)=0$
and used a point before $-4$, between $-4$,$-9$ and after $-9$
and pug it back in the $f(t)$.

Did I do it right?

Thanks

Comment: On the denominator is it supposed to be $[\cos x]^2$ or $\cos(x^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in recognizing that $f'(t)=0$ when $t=-4,-9$. The next step is to take the second derivative of $f$ with respect to $t$ to get
$$f''(t)=\frac{(2x+13)(1+\cos^2x)+\sin(2x)(x^2+13x+36)}{(1+\cos^2x)^2}$$
We have
$$f''(-4)=5(1+\cos^2(-4))(1+\cos^2(-4))^{-2}>0$$
making the graph concave up at $t=-4$ thus $f(-4)$ is a local minimum. Again for $t=-9$ we have
$$f''(-9)=-5(1+\cos^2(-9))(1+\cos^2(-9))^{-2}<0$$
making the graph concave down at $t=-9$ and thus $f(-9)$ is a local maximum.
You could also do it the way that you were hinting at by comparing the values of $f'(t_1)$, $f'(t_2)$, and $f'(t_3)$ for $t_1<-9$, $t_2\in(-9,-4)$, $t_3>-4$. Then looking at how the signs change.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first derivative is positive up to $-9$, then negative up to $-4$, then positive. So there is a local max at $-9$ and a local min at $-4$.

I do not know of any way of *evaluating* the function at the local max and local min except numerically, say using Simpson's Rule.